# Which module will allow a user to grant another user permissions for editing content of content type

Tags: users, nodes

I have a content type of 'project' and I want the creator of this content type to be able to allocate other users to be 'admins' on this project, so they have extended rights to edit the project details, archive the project, approve users attached to that project.
Is there a module that sounds like it can achieve some of this stuff?
thanks

Comment: [Workbench](https://drupal.org/project/workbench) perhaps?

Comment: if Workbench doesn't work for your needs, you might want to look at the list of node access modules available ( https://drupal.org/node/270000 ) and in particular the node access user reference module ( https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference )

Comment: workbench and rules can provide a flexible content moderation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are existing permissions on your site already and you just want to control delegation, it sounds like you might want the [Roleassign](https://drupal.org/project/roleassign) module.

> RoleAssign specifically allows site administrators to further delegate the task of managing user's roles while withholding the Administer permissions permission.
>
> RoleAssign introduces a new permission called Assign roles. Users with this permission are able to assign selected roles to still other users. Only users with the Administer permissions permission may select which roles are available for assignment through this module.

If that is not sufficient for your needs, a combination of Roleassign and [Workbench Access](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_access) would likely serve your needs.

> Workbench Access creates editorial access controls based on hierarchies. It is an extensible system that supports structures created by other Drupal modules.
>
> When creating and editing content, users will be asked to place the content in an editorial section. Other users within that section or its parents will be able to edit the content. A user may be granted editorial rights to a section specific to his account or by his assigned role on the site.

A combination of these two modules would likely be more than adequate for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As a specific scenario: If a user creates a content type of project and as creator of that project they have special permissions to edit, delete etc. Is it possible that that user can also 'grant' permisssions to another user to also have these special permissions. Does this sounds achieveable with the above?

Comment: although this looks pretty good: https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference